# mod_rewrite pretty URL doesn't stay

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i needed my URL

> /crescenty/**name**

to redirect to

> /crescenty/profile.php?player=**name**

I've used this mod_rewrite code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /crescenty/$1/ [NC,R]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/$ /crescenty/profile.php?player=$1 [NC,R]
```

But there is a slight problem, the URL doesn't stay, it kept going back to

> /crescenty/profile.php?player=**name**

I tried using the above mod_rewrite code with flag on the last line as [NC,L], the URL stays the way i want it to which is

> /crescenty/**name**

but the page doesn't show up properly (css doesn't seem to apply)

please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because your links are defined as relative to *the current directory*.

When you rewrite the URL it has one lower level than the original URL (/crescenty/ vs **/crescenty/name/**). This means resources will be looked for relative to the second directory level which of course won't work.

Change your resource URLs to use URLs relative to the *web root* by adding a **leading slash** to your links.

For example change <img href="*images/mying.jpg*" /> to <img href="**/images/mying.jpg**" /> (notice the leading slash).

Comment: But it seem that if i were to do so, it works for the rest but then now that my main page doesn't show up right (127.0.0.1/crescenty/).

Comment: I suggest you looking into techniques on debugging network resources. For example Firefox's [Firebug plugin](https://getfirebug.com/) has a "Net" tab where you can see all the HTTP requests being made on the page. Chrome and IE (from IE9 I believe) also has network tabs out-of-the-box among their developer tools set. Otherwise I can recommend a good browser-agnostic tool called [Fiddler](https://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).